# No Cancela una Alarma

Tags: kotlin

Estoy probando setear y cancelar una alarma en android studio con Kotlin. Para ello pido la fecha y la hora correspondientes por pantalla. Utilizo dos botones, uno para ejecutar y otro para cancelar. Luego de presionado el boton Start, la alarma se ejecuta correctamente a la hora indicada. Al presionar el boton de cancelacion btnCancel, el codigo ejecuta (lo comprobe con debug) pero NO CANCELA LA ALARMA, la cual sigue sonando hasta cumplir 30 segundos tras lo cual se apaga por si misma. En que le estoy errando? Gracias.

Este es el codigo de la MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var pendingIntent:PendingIntent
    lateinit var alarmManager: AlarmManager
    //lateinit var intent:Intent
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var start = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        var btnCancel:Button= findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnCancel)
        start.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { startAlert() })
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { cancelAlert() })
    }

    fun startAlert() {
        val dateTV: EditText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dateTV)
        // transformo la fecha
        var inicio = Calendar.getInstance()
        //
        var dia:Int = dateTV.text.toString().substring(0..1).toInt()
        var mes:Int = dateTV.text.toString().substring(3..4).toInt()
        var anio:Int = dateTV.text.toString().substring(6..9).toInt()
        // Calculo hora y minutos en milisegundos
        var horaMS:Int= timeTV.text.toString().substring(0..1).toInt()*60*60*1000
        var mintutoMS = timeTV.text.toString().substring(3..4).toInt()*60*1000
        //
        inicio.set(anio,mes-1,dia)
        inicio.set(Calendar.HOUR,0)
        inicio.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0)
        inicio.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0)
        inicio.set(Calendar.SECOND,0)
        // Tiempo de la alarma (dia mas horas y minutos) en ms:
        var inicioMS:Long=inicio.timeInMillis+horaMS+mintutoMS
        // hora actual en ms:
        var ahoraMS:Long=System.currentTimeMillis()
        //diferencia entre hora actual y dia/hora de la alarma, en ms:
        var ms: Long=(Math.abs(ahoraMS-inicioMS))
        intent = Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 234324243, intent, 0)
        alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        // Set de la alarma:
        alarmManager[AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + ms] = pendingIntent
    }
    fun cancelAlert(){
        intent = Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        //val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 123, intent, 0)
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 234324243, intent, 0)
        alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent)
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo de la clase MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.widget.Toast

class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    //var mp: MediaPlayer? = null
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        var mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.alarm)
        mp.start()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disculpas por la pregunta. Mal planteada porque estaba mal interpretado lo que quería decir "cancelar". La cancelación sí se efectua, pero refiere a que no se ejecute una alarma establecida para ejecutarse a determinada hora, no a parar el sonido de una alarma ya en ejecución en determinado momento.